# Show that $A\subseteq B\implies A^{\circ} \subseteq B^{\circ}$ in a different way.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a metric space $(M,d)$. If $A\subseteq B$, then $A^{\circ} \subseteq B^{\circ}$.

**Proof** :  Assume that $a\in A^{\circ}$. Then there exists a $r>0$ such that $K(a,r)\subseteq A$. Since $A\subseteq B$ it shows that $K(a,r)\subseteq B$, then $a\in B^{\circ}$.

I wondered if it's possible to *write it differently*, but I am not sure if it's correct,
\begin{align}
A^{\circ}&=\left \{x\in M \mid \exists r>0: K(x,r)\subseteq A \right \}\\
&\subseteq \left \{x\in M \mid \exists r>0: K(x,r)\subseteq B \right \}\qquad (\textrm{since } A\subseteq B)\\
&=B^{\circ}.
\end{align}

Comment: That's not a different way! That's the same proof, just written differently.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, that's what I meant. I've edited it.

Comment: Your first proof is more rigorously correct.

Comment: This is actually the same proof. In the first proof you stop before concluding that $A^° \subset B^°$ because $\forall x(x \in A^° \Longrightarrow x \in B^°)$, and in the second, you don't justify why $\{x \ | \ \exists r > 0: K(x,r) \subset A\} \subset \{x \ | \ \exists r > 0: K(x,r) \subset B\}$.

Comment: @nombre I thought it's better left it unmentioned since $A$ is assumed to be a subset of $B$, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I agree. I just mentionned that because the differences between the two proofs were subtle to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, but it's not really 'another way'.  What you've done is taken the first proof and expressed it in set-theoretic language.  This is often a useful thing to do, though the first proof has the advantage that everything is explained in words rather than with symbols.

Comment: There are some proofs explained in words that are not easy to understand. That's why I mostly prefer something that is explained with symbols.